# How to Format an Output Table using Latex?

Tags: r, latex

I was working on some categorical variables and created a contingency table using the following code:

```
mytable <- table(Gender, Income)
```

The output looks like below (which is not nice-looking):

```
  Work.Status
Gender   Employed Full-time Employed Part-time Unemployed
  Male                  433                 35         29
  Female                427                174        247
```

Is there any way that I can format this table to make it better looking (e.g. change the font, color, and size of the variables)? I tried a few methods from the web, but didn't get the desired results....

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear from your question what you want to achieve. Is this an R to latex question or is it simply a formatting in latex question?

I favour the xtable package in R for taking tables in R to latex. A very quick example for categorical data below. The knitr package is also excellent for combining R with Latex output.

```
   library(xtable)
   data(tli)
   head(tli)
   table(tli$sex, tli$grade)
   print(xtable(table(tli$sex, tli$grade), booktabs = TRUE))
```

Which returns

```
% latex table generated in R 3.0.0 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Thu Nov 28 09:00:24 2013
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 
  \hline
F &   6 &   9 &   8 &  11 &  10 &   7 \\ 
  M &   9 &   6 &   7 &  12 &   8 &   7 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```